# Angular Router - Nested Child with id

Tags: angular, angular-router

Part of my angular router looks like this:

```
{
  path: 'things',
  component: ThingsComponent,
  children: [
    {
      path: ':id',
      component: ThingDetailComponent
    }
  ]
}
```

When hitting `localhost:4200/things/3`, why is it landing on `ThingsComponent` and not `ThingDetailComponent`?

Answer (score 0):

Insead specifying detail route as a child, you can do routing like that:

```
{
    path: 'things',
    component: ThingComponent,
  },
  {
    path: 'things/:id',
    component: ThingDetailComponent
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to replace `path: ':id'` with `path: 'things/:id'` to get it done.

Answer (score 0):

like that:

```
{
  path: 'things', 
  children: [
  {
    path: '',
    component: ThingsComponent,
  },

  {
    path: ':id',
    component: ThingDetailComponent
  }
 ]
}
```